# Django getting related objects in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm pretty new to Django and Python in general and I'm working on my first solo app and I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do something with my models:

```
class A(models.Model):
    bs = models.ManyToManyField('B', null=True, blank=True, related_query_name='the_thing', db_table='A_B_relation')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 
        return self.name

class B(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 
        return self.name
```

What I want to do is get a list of all the objects of A that are related to a specific object of B, is this possible?

I can filter all of B with a related name from A and get the list of all the things in B that have that relation:

```
>>> B.objects.filter(the_thing__name='abc')
    [/B: Bob>, /B: Jim>]
```

(the "/" should be "<", not sure how to format that), so I thought it would be possible to sort of go the other way around.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to indent the `__str__` one level to the right.

Comment: Thanks, it's correct in my source, just formatted incorrectly here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a list of A objects that are related to a specific B object:

```
b_object = B.objects.get(name='Bob')
A.objects.filter(bs=b_object)
```

If you a list of B objects

```
b_object_list = B.objects.filter(name__in=['Bob', 'Jim'])
A.objects.filter(bs__in=b_object_list)
```